# Greasemonkey/Chrome Extension cross domain login or session

Tags: ajax, google-chrome, authentication, cross-domain, greasemonkey

I wrote a set of APIs which will consider you authenticated if you logged on the website (and therefore you have your *cookies set*).

I then wrote a Greasemonkey and a Google Chrome plugin that does different calls to my `api/*` calls. However, Ajax doesnt send *cookie header* over *cross domain* (remember it is plugin that is enabled when you are on facebook).

What are the best strategies to **authenticate** my user and **authorize** his api calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
GM_xmlhttpRequest
```

indeed does an AJAX-call and sends the cookie header.
You can therefore simply call a website that returns the authentification status based on visitors cookies, return a simple result and use it.

**Example**

```
GM_xmlhttpRequest({ 
method: "GET",  
     url: "http://yourwebsite/loggedin.php",    
     onload: function(resp) {
     var conti=resp.responseText;
     loggedin = parseInt(conti); //let the webpage return 1 or 0
```

Comment: thanks! however this satisfy greasemonkey, not google chrome :(

Comment: I'm not really into google chrome extension development, but can't you simply let the user on the first visit redirect to your page, let them log in, and then save some kind of unique combination in the browser. This parameters could be provided over GET in every request to authentificate the user.

Comment: See the documentation of chromes own cookie system here: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/cookies.html Be sure to get the right permissions and then save the code in a cookie. Retrieve it the next times and use it for any calls.